# WP7 implementing data virtualization

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to implement the data virtualization, but I dont know where to put my real collection of data in this example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/16/virtualizing-data-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-applications.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say your collection is List where Person is a Custom Class you have defined.

You should read a small subset of data from either a Service or Isolated Storage and set it as below.

In the VirtualizedDataSource.cs file update the getter of "this" property as under

```
 if (itemToReturn == null)
 {
      if (simpleCache.Count >= CACHE_SIZE)
      {
        DataItem oldItem = simpleCache.Dequeue();
        Debug.WriteLine("Purging\t" + oldItem.Index + "\t" + oldItem.Text);
        oldItem.Text = "DEAD ITEM";
      }

      itemToReturn = **new Person();**
      text += "\t" + itemToReturn.Text;
      simpleCache.Enqueue(itemToReturn);
 }
```

Hope this helps.